# Show number of integers $m$ with $1\leq m\leq n$, divisible by $p^h$ is equal to $\left[\frac{n}{p^h}\right]$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $p$ a prime number.

Show that for each $h\in\mathbb{N}$, the number of integers $m$, with $1\leq m\leq n$, divisible by $p^h$ is equal to $\left[\frac{n}{p^h}\right]$, where $\left[\theta\right]$ denotes integer part of $\theta$.

I can see how this works for simple examples of $n$ and $p$. I have no real idea as to how to begin proving this.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've edited the answer some days ago, It's now more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: How many integers $k \in \mathbb{N}$ are such that the product  $p^hk$ is smaller than $n$?

Let's $X$ be the set of this integer.

Let's $Y$ be the set of integers $m$ such that $m < n$ and $p^h | m$

Now We have to make some observation:

1. If $m$ is in $Y$ , you can write $m$ as the product $kp^h$ in a unique form, where $k$ is an integer contained in $X$.
2. If $k$ is in $X$, the product $m=kp^h$ is an integer smaller than $n$ and such that $p^h|m$, so contained in $Y$.

You can see how to conclude? (The claim is that there exist a bijection between $X$ and $Y$)